# PNG compression using pngquant, correct shell command in php-script

Tags: php, apache, shell

```
function compress_png($path_to_png_file, $max_quality = 90)
{
    if (!file_exists($path_to_png_file)) {
        throw new Exception("File does not exist: $path_to_png_file");
    }
    $min_quality = 60;
    $compressed_png_content = shell_exec("pngquant --quality=$min_quality-$max_quality - < ".escapeshellarg($path_to_png_file));
    if (!$compressed_png_content) {
        throw new Exception("Conversion to compressed PNG failed. Is pngquant 1.8+ installed on the server?");
    }
    return $compressed_png_content;
}
$read_from_path = "pic.png";
$save_to_path = "compressed_file.png";
$compressed_png_content = compress_png($read_from_path);
file_put_contents($save_to_path, $compressed_png_content);
```

this code return error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Conversion to compressed PNG failed. Is pngquant 1.8+ installed on the server?' 
>   Stack trace: compress_png('pic.png', 60) #1 {main} thrown in

how to write a shell command? and how to install pngquant the server: windows server 2008 r2 sp1, php 5.5.5, apache 2.4. File for windows downloaded here: http://pngquant.org/pngquant-windows.zip

Comment: Start by specifying the full path of `pngquant`.  PATH might not be defined as you expect.  Next, make sure you don't have a permissions problem.  Apache might be running as LOCAL SERVICE or some other account, which is what PHP is probably running as.  Also, be sure to escape the values for min/max quality as you have for the file name.  I would also verify that they are integers.

Comment: does not work, you have the example of the command, with an example of the file structure? i want example